# JMeter for Single Iteration Summary Report does not match the Total No of Threads

Tags: jmeter

Below is the Test Design for the bzm-Concurrency Thread Group. There is no issue in the Test execution. The problem I am seeing is in the Summary Report in No.Of Samples. I expected 350 Samples as No.Of Iterations per thread i have given is:1, and since for out of 1500 users after 350 user logging Ran in to the error and test has sopped as designed.
Can some one please shed the lights here.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong. If you set "Thread iterations limit" to 1 it basically means that when your thread (virtual user) finishes execution of all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) defined under your Thread Group it will be shut down.

If the desired test duration is not reached yet **another new thread will start** and this explains the fact you're getting more than 1500 sample results.

The total number of executed requests will mainly depend on your system under test response time.

A couple more things to consider:

1. According to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) (or whatever is the current stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. According to the same JMeter Best Practices [you should use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating
3. I don't see you Beanshell Sampler code but given its name it seems that you're writing something into a file and this is wrong approach as you will get corrupt results due to race conditions, consider switching to i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) instead.

Comment: #3. I am writing the Token into the file.  So If I want to achieve exact 1500 samples can i use Throughput Controller --Total Executions : 1500